# Better way to demand, in SQL, that a column contains every specified value

Tags: sql, select, one-to-many

Imagine you have two tables, with a one to many relationship.

For this example, I will suggest that there are two tables:  Person, and Homes.
The person table holds a persons name, and gives them an ID.  The homes table, holds the association of homes to a person.  PID joins to "Person.ID"

And, in this tiny DB, a person can have no homes, or many homes.

[image]

*I hope I drew that right.*

**How do I write a select, that returns everyone with *every* specified house type?**

Let's say these are valid "Types" in the homes table:

> Cottage, Main, Mansion, Spaceport.

I want to return everyone, in the Person table, who has a spaceport *and* a Cottage.

The best I could come up with was this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.name ) AS name
FROM person p
    INNER JOIN homes h ON h.pid = p.id
WHERE 'spaceport' in (
    SELECT DISTINCT( type ) AS type
    FROM homes
    WHERE pid = p.id
)
AND 'cottage' in (
    SELECT DISTINCT( type ) AS type
    FROM homes
    WHERE pid = p.id
)
```

When I wrote that, it works, but I'm pretty sure there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HAVING clause here will guarantee that the persons returned have *both* types, not just one or the other.

```
SELECT p.name
    FROM person p
        INNER JOIN homes h
            ON p.id = h.pid
                AND h.type IN ('spaceport', 'cottage')
    GROUP BY p.name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.type) = 2
```

Comment: Wont't this return the name of someone with a spaceport and a mansion?

Comment: @Patrick: The `INNER JOIN` is looking for 'spaceport' and 'cottage' only. No 'mansion' records will match that join condition.

Comment: @Patrick: Also note the `COUNT(distinct h.type) = 2` which guarantees only the two types specified.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from homes;

home_id  person_id  type
--
1        1          cottage
2        1          mansion
3        2          cottage
4        3          mansion
5        4          cottage
6        4          cottage
```

To find the id numbers of every person who has both a cottage *and* a mansion, group by the id number, restrict the output to cottages and mansions, and count the distinct types.

```
select person_id
from homes
where type in ('cottage','mansion')
group by person_id
having count(distinct type) = 2;

person_id
--
1
```

You can use this query in a join to get all the columns from the person table.

```
select person.* 
from person
inner join (select person_id
            from homes
            where type in ('cottage','mansion')
            group by person_id
            having count(distinct type) = 2) T
on person.person_id = T.person_id;
```

Thanks to Joe for pointing out an error in my count().

Comment: What if a person owned two cottages and no other properties? Your query would return that person. That's why you need to count *distinct* types in the `HAVING` clause, as I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554677/better-way-to-demand-in-sql-that-a-coumn-contains-every-specified-value/5554727#5554727).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance on this one, but here goes:

```
SELECT PID FROM (
    SELECT PID, COUNT(PID) cnt FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT PID, Type FROM Homes 
        WHERE Type IN ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3')
    ) a
    GROUP BY PID
) b
WHERE b.cnt = 3
```

You'd have to dynamically generate your `IN` clause as well as the WHERE `b.CNT` clause.